# Laravel Passport Scopes is not throwing error but neither giving correct answer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

Hello I am not sure what I am doing wrong in this project where I am trying to use scopes in queries.

[This image is how my api.php folder looks like when I remove the scope: view-products then it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuCjC.png)

I think I have setup everything correctly both kernel and auth service provider

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NViF.png)

[this is response I get on my postman when I try to make request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8r9H.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Add the following middleware to the $routeMiddleware property of your app/Http/Kernel.php file:**

'scopes' => \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckScopes::class,
'scope' => \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckForAnyScope::class,

**Change your middle from:**
Route::middleware(['scope: view-products'])...
**To this**
Route::middlware(['scopre:view-products'])

Comment: I already have the first one sorry I forgot to add it here as image and the second one did not help :/ I know what you mean there is the space but I think I found the problem but I have no idea how to solve it, in my request I dont have the client for some reason I just have $request->client() and its null it should not be from what I can tell as can be see in fille from laravel CheckScopes.php

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).